# Find by nested and other column in mongo never returns data

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following query:

```
{'carCollectionStatuses': 'BELOW_ONE_HUNDRED', 'carCollection.carID':'e711c3aa-e073-0cd4-29e0-db2e503b61a0'}
```

Which returns:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a4bf83ae261b4cc9045d36d"), 
    "name" : "Colecao cabrita", 
    "title" : "Colecao selecionada a dedo", 
    "subtitle" : "Só carros que vão parar de funcionar", 
    "pictureUrl" : "http://www.google.com", 
    "carCollection" : [
        {
            "partnerName" : "-------", 
            "photo" : "https://--------", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("59d7cac33fde150006d24856"), 
            "location" : [
                11123.21729, 
                1146.4362
            ], 
            "carModel" : "LOGAN Expression Hi-Flex 1.6 8V 4p", 
            "carBrand" : "Renault", 
            "carID" : "e711c3aa-e073-0cd4-29e0-db2e222b61a0"
        }, 
        {
            "partnerName" : "-------", 
            "photo" : "---------", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("59dbc9701755db00069a4157"), 
            "location" : [
                11123.21729, 
                1146.4362
            ], 
            "carModel" : "Megane Grand Tour Dynam. Hi-Flex 1.6 16V", 
            "carBrand" : "Renault", 
            "carID" : "e71125ad-70fc-f563-0000-db2e503b61a0"
        }
    ], 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0), 
    "carCollectionStatuses" : [
        "BELOW_ONE_HUNDRED"
    ]
}
```

Using spring-data-mongodb:

```
@Query("{'carCollectionStatuses': ?0, 'carCollection.carID': ?1}")
CarCollectionHolderEntity findBycarCollectionStatusesAndCarCollectionCarID(CarCollectionStatus status, String carID);
```

My problem is, using MQL directly I have a matching query, but using spring-mongo this query never returns the data, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The first thing that caught my eye, method name `findBycarCollectionStatusesAndCarCollectionCarID`  -> `findByCarCollectionStatusesAndCarCollectionCarID`. `Car ' - with a capital letter.

Comment: Changing to capital C didn`t make any difference. Thanks !